# Horizontal drag slide help! <html <jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i make a horizontal drag scroll with html/css/jquery.
I'm trying to make it like a phone home screen where you can move through the slides.
lets say i have 2 div's and i have them like 2 slides on a phone. I want to drag scroll from the first div the the other and back the same way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please attempt to do it yourself first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can check for iscroll

https://jonathanstark.com/labs/iscroll/examples/horizontal-scroll/

home page

http://iscrolljs.com/